# Comment boxes only post with first post in MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view in my MVC application that is designed to show views and comments gathered from a database, and allow users to make posts and comments accordingly.

The relevant section of Html is below:

```
<div style="background-color:#fff1fc; height:100vh; width:810px; float:left; border-radius: 8px; margin: 5px">
        <div>
            <p>

                <center>
                @foreach (var item in Model.PostList)
                {
                    <div style="background-color: white; height:auto; width: 810px; border-radius: 8px; margin: 5px; text-align: left; text-size-adjust: 50%; text-anchor:start; font-size: larger">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Profile.FirstName)&nbsp;
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Profile.LastName)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Project.ProjectName)<br/>
                        <div style="text-align:center; text-size-adjust: auto">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Text)<br/>
                        </div>
                        <div style="text-align: right; text-size-adjust: 20%; text-anchor: end">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DATE)
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                        <div style="line-break:initial; font-size:small; text-align: left; margin: 10px; padding: 10px">
                        @Html.Label("Comments:")<br/>

                        <br/>
                        @foreach (var comment in Model.CommentList)
                        {
                            if (comment.PostId == item.Id)
                            {
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelComment => comment.Profile.FirstName)
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelComment => comment.Profile.LastName) 
                                <br/>
                                <center>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelComment => comment.Comment1)
                                <hr />
                                <br/>

                                </center>   
                            }

                        }
                            <center>
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => Model.Comment, new { @class = "height: 200px, width: 600px"})
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                <right>
                                <input type="submit" value="Comment" class="btn btn-default" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="PostId" value="@item.Id" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="ProfileId" value="@Model.ProfileList[0].Id" />
                                </right>
                                <br />

                            </center>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
                </center>

            </p>
        </div>
   </div>
```

So, for each item in PostList, the relevant attributes of that list are displayed. With these posts, each item from the CommentList that references this post is also displayed, with a TextBox to make a new comment. This all works fine! The problem appears to be here:

```
 <center>
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => Model.Comment, new { @class = "height: 200px, width: 600px"})
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                <right>
                                <input type="submit" value="Comment" class="btn btn-default" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="PostId" value="@item.Id" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="ProfileId" value="@Model.ProfileList[0].Id" />
                                </right>
                                <br />

                            </center>
```

For some reason, when I attempt to make a comment on my platform, it only works if commenting on the most recent/first post on the feed (The first item). Attempting to make a comment on anything other than the first item, does nothing. Here is the Post method of my controller:

```
public ActionResult Post(string Text, int Id, string Comment, int ProfileId, int PostId)
    {

        if (Text != "")
        {
            using (var ctx = new SocialDBEntities())
            {
                string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();




                Post post = new CrowdSocial2.Post();
                post.ProfileId = Id;
                post.DATE = System.DateTime.Now.Date;
                post.Text = Text;
                db.Posts.Add(post);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Feed");

            }
        }
        else if (Comment != "")
        {
            string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

            Comment comment = new CrowdSocial2.Comment();
            comment.PostId = PostId;
            comment.ProfileId = ProfileId;
            comment.Comment1 = Comment;
            comment.Date = System.DateTime.Now.Date;
            db.Comments.Add(comment);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Feed");
        }

        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Feed");
        }

    }
```

The controller is passed Comment, and determines whether or not it is "null". If not, it will post the comment to the database with the accompanying postId and profileId. Since this wasn't working, I decided to put a breakpoint on the RedirectToAction both inside of the if(Comment != "") statement, and in the elseif statement to see what was happening.

Turns out, Comment for some reason is being passed as "" regardless of what was written in the comment box, the controller is seeing it as "" and hence just redirects back to the view. This makes me suspect that what is happening is that Comment is being passed from the very first comment box, which is empty.

Any ideas how I can fix this so that I can comment on any of the post items?

Comment: This is because `@Html.TextAreaFor(m => ...)` si created for every comment so the generated `textarea` will have the same `ID`. If i were you i would create a property inside my `Model.CommentList` called `MyComment` and create the textarea for it. This will give you a different id for each input. Also you should use `for` loops instead of `foreach`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try!